# Amazon Quicksight - Dynamic filter latest week by default

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I think the question is fairly simple. I would like to have a dynamic filter on Quicksight. I have the column week which is a number (3, 4, 5 and 6) for example. The data is refreshed every week.

We want to show only the latest week by default (out of weeks 3, 4, 5 and 6, I want to filter by default on 6), but then the users can select if they want to see more weeks.

The week after, the default filter would be 7, and so on.

Is there a way to tell the filter to automatically filter by rule of MAX(week) or something like that?

It would be very helpful. I have other alternatives but they are not that great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second solution.

- Add Filter
- Choose week
- Type Top and Bottom Filter
- Show Top write 1
- By week ( use max aggregation)

Pasting an image from an analysis that I do the same thing for integer column year

[image]

Comment: Hi sorry. Yes that's the one I came up with last night. Still not ideal, but very simple.

Only issue is that to look into a particular week you need to add the extra week filter so it's two steps. You look at newest by default, if you want to look at the week -3, you need to change the 1 to a 3 or 4, then select the week from the dropdown list in a separate filter.

Still, it answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose a date field that I understand that must exist in your data and then create a dynamic filter on that date field.

You create filters on **date fields** by selecting the filter conditions and date values that you want to use. There are three filter types for dates:
For your case, you will have to use

**Relative** – A series of date/time elements based on the current date. You can filter records based on the current date and your selected unit of measure (UOM). Date filter units include years, quarters, months, weeks, days, hours, and minutes.

Use the following procedure to create a relative filter for a date field.

- On the toolbar at the left, choose Filter.
- In the Filters pane that opens at left, choose the plus icon (+), and then choose a date field to filter on.
- A new filter is added to the Filters pane.
- In the Filters pane, choose the new filter to expand it.
- For Filter type, choose Relative dates.
- Choose a unit of time (week for your case).
- Choose how you want the filter to relate to the time frame. For example, if you choose to report on weeks, your options are previous week, this week, week to date, last N weeks, and next N weeks.

If you choose Last n UOM, specify a number for your range—for example, last 2 weeks, or last 1 week.

Comment: The issue here is that the week is the way the data is grouped, so the dataset I have has a column with the week and that's it. No date references.

Comment: then you will have to use a parameter. Check this link. It is self explanatory
https://quicksight-covid19-labs.workshop.aws/en/create_customize_4/parameters.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't know it seems very complicated. Just want to have by default the max value of a column. There it shows it for a date example